# Wordpress Payment gateway add on form , how to add form into list or else how to submit form to next step for payment

Tags: plugins, php

The blow code in my payment.php file and I am taking data from config in admin using filter in wordpress..

```
    function wpjb_payment_clickandpledge($list,$html) {
      global $wpjobboard;
     global $gclass;
      global $html;
      include_once dirname(__FILE__)."/clickandpledge_payment.class.php";
      $cnp = new Payment_ClickandPledge();
      $list[$cnp->getEngine()] = get_class($cnp);
      return $list;
    }
 add_filter('wpjb_payments_list',  'wpjb_payment_clickandpledge');
```

In code add_filter function used to get payment gateway list enabled in admin area..in that my custom gateway also display ..but now in that after details i need form to enter payment details like credit or other payments , I have one class file which is having my form and it is assigned to $html variable inside the function called **function render()** ...Now i want to add my $html to add_filter('wpjb_payments_list', 'wpjb_payment_clickandpledge'); for this hooks how can do this below is my class file

```
    class Payment_ClickandPledge extends Wpjb_Payment_Abstract{ 
         public function render() {
        $data = $this->_data;$id = $this->_data->id; $availableCurrencies = array();$paymentMethods = array();
        $merchant = $this->getMerchant(); 
         <form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form"><h3>'.__("Click & Pledge", "wpjobboard").'</h3>
        <div class="payment-errors"></div><div class="htmlholder">  ';
        if(count($paymentMethods) > 0) {$html .= '<span style="width:980px" id="payment_methods">';foreach($paymentMethods as $pkey => $pval) {
        if($pkey == $defaultpayment) {
        $html .= '<input type="radio" id="cnp_payment_method_selection_'.$pkey.'" name="cnp_payment_method_selection" class="cnp_payment_method_selection" style="margin: 0 0 0 0;" value="'.$pkey.'" checked>&nbsp<b>'.$pval.'</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        } else {$html .= '<input type="radio" id="cnp_payment_method_selection_'.$pkey.'" name="cnp_payment_method_selection" class="cnp_payment_method_selection" style="margin: 0 0 0 0;" value="'.$pkey.'">&nbsp;<b>'.$pval.'</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        }}$html .= '</span>';}
         $cdivdisplay = ($defaultpayment == 'CreditCard') ? 'block' : 'none';$recurringhtml = '';
            $merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_isRecurring'].'############';
         if(isset($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_isRecurring']) && $merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_isRecurring'] == 1) {
        if($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_RecurringLabel'] != '') {
            $recurringhtml .= '<br><div class="form-row" id="clickandpledge_isRecurring_div"><label>
            <span>'.__($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_RecurringLabel'], "wpjobboard").'</span> <input type="checkbox" name="clickandpledge_isRecurring" id="clickandpledge_isRecurring"/></label></div>';} else {
        $recurringhtml .= '<br><div class="form-row" id="clickandpledge_isRecurring_div"><label><span>'.__('Is this Recurring Payment?', "wpjobboard").'</span><input type="checkbox" name="clickandpledge_isRecurring" id="clickandpledge_isRecurring"/></label>
        </div>';}$RecurringMethod = array();
if(isset($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_RecurringMethod_Subscription']) && is_array($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_RecurringMethod_Subscription']) && count($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_RecurringMethod_Subscription']) > 0) {   array_push($RecurringMethod, 'Subscription');}
if(isset($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_RecurringMethod_Installment']) && is_array($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_RecurringMethod_Installment']) && count($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_RecurringMethod_Installment']) > 0) {
         array_push($RecurringMethod, 'Installment');}
        if(count($RecurringMethod) == 0) {array_push($RecurringMethod, 'Subscription');
        array_push($RecurringMethod, 'Installment');}if(count($RecurringMethod) > 0) {
        if(count($RecurringMethod) == 1) {$recurringhtml .= '<input type="hidden" name="clickandpledge_RecurringMethod" id="clickandpledge_RecurringMethod" value="'.$RecurringMethod[0].'">';
        } else {$recurringhtml .= '<br><div class="form-row" id="clickandpledge_RecurringMethod_div"><label>
        <span>'.__("Recurring Method", "wpjobboard").'</span>
         <select id="clickandpledge_RecurringMethod" name="clickandpledge_RecurringMethod">';
        foreach ($RecurringMethod as $r) {$recurringhtml .= '<option value="'.$r.'">'.$r.'</option>';}  
        $recurringhtml .= '</select></label> </div>';}} else {
        $recurringhtml .= '<div class="form-row" id="clickandpledge_RecurringMethod_div"><label>
        <span>'.__("Recurring Method", "wpjobboard").'</span>
        <select id="clickandpledge_RecurringMethod" name="clickandpledge_RecurringMethod">
        <option value="Subscription">Subscription</option>
        <option value="Installment">Installment</option></select></label> </div>';}
      if(isset($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_indefinite']) && is_array($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_indefinite']) && count($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_indefinite']) > 0) {
                        $recurringhtml .= '<br><div class="form-row" id="clickandpledge_indefinite_div">
        <label><span>'.__("Indefinite Recurring", "wpjobboard").'</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="clickandpledge_indefinite" id="clickandpledge_indefinite"/></label></div>';}
  if(isset($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_Periodicity']) && is_array($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_Periodicity']) && count($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_Periodicity']) > 0) {
 $recurringhtml .= '<br><div class="form-row" id="clickandpledge_Periodicity_div">
        <label><span>'.__("Every", "wpjobboard").'</span> <select id="clickandpledge_Periodicity" name="clickandpledge_Periodicity">';
        foreach ($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_Periodicity'] as $r) {$recurringhtml .= '<option value="'.$r.'">'.$r.'</option>';
        }  $recurringhtml .= '</select></label>&nbsp;<span id="clickandpledge_Installment_div"><input type="text" name="clickandpledge_Installment" id="clickandpledge_Installment" class="required" title="Installments" style="width:100px;" maxlength="3"/>&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">*</font> payments</span>
        </div> <script>jQuery("#clickandpledge_Installment").keypress(function(e) {
        var a = [];var k = e.which;for (i = 48; i < 58; i++) a.push(i);if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0))e.preventDefault();
        });</script>';} else {$Periodicity = array();$Periodicity['Week']       = 'Week';$Periodicity['2 Weeks']    = '2 Weeks';
        $Periodicity['2 Months']    = '2 Months';$Periodicity['Quarter']    = 'Quarter';
        $Periodicity['6 Months']    = '6 Months';
         $Periodicity['Year']       = 'Year';           
        $recurringhtml .= '<br><div class="form-row" id="clickandpledge_Periodicity_div">
        <label><span>'.__("Every", "wpjobboard").'</span> <select id="clickandpledge_Periodicity" name="clickandpledge_Periodicity">';
        foreach ($Periodicity as $k => $v) {
  $recurringhtml .= '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';
                                }  
                                $recurringhtml .= '</select>
                                </label>&nbsp;
                                <span id="clickandpledge_Installment_div"><input type="text" name="clickandpledge_Installment" id="clickandpledge_Installment" class="required" title="Installments" style="width:100px;" maxlength="3"/>&nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">*</font> payments</span> </div>
                              ';  }        }
                         $clickandpledgename_CreditCard = '<div class="form-row cnp_payment_style" >  <label>
   <span>'.__("Name&nbsp;<font color='red'>*</font>", "wpjobboard").'</span>
<input type="text" size="20" data-clickandpledge="number" name="clickandpledge_FirstName_CreditCard" id="clickandpledge_FirstName_CreditCard" class="required NameOnCard" placeholder="First Name"/><input type="text" size="20" data-clickandpledge="number" name="clickandpledge_LastName_CreditCard" id="clickandpledge_LastName_CreditCard" class="required NameOnCard" placeholder="Last Name"/>  </label></div> ';
$clickandpledgename_eCheck = '<div class="form-row cnp_payment_style" >
<label> <span>'.__("Name&nbsp;<font color='red'>*</font>", "wpjobboard").'</span><input type="text" size="20" data-clickandpledge="number" name="clickandpledge_FirstName_eCheck" id="clickandpledge_FirstName_eCheck" class="required NameOnCard" placeholder="First Name"/>
<input type="text" size="20" data-clickandpledge="number" name="clickandpledge_LastName_eCheck" id="clickandpledge_LastName_eCheck" class="required NameOnCard" placeholder="Last Name"/></label>  </div>   ';
                          $clickandpledgename_Invoice = '<div class="form-row cnp_payment_style" ><label> <span>'.__("Name&nbsp;<font color='red'>*</font>", "wpjobboard").'</span><input type="text" size="20" data-clickandpledge="number" name="clickandpledge_FirstName_Invoice" id="clickandpledge_FirstName_Invoice" class="required NameOnCard"  placeholder="First Name"/>
                              <input type="text" size="20" data-clickandpledge="number" name="clickandpledge_LastName_Invoice" id="clickandpledge_LastName_Invoice" class="required NameOnCard"  placeholder="Last Name"/> </label> </div> ';
                          $clickandpledgename_PO = '<div class="form-row cnp_payment_style" ><label>
                              <span>'.__("Name&nbsp;<font color='red'>*</font>", "wpjobboard").'</span> <input type="text" size="20" data-clickandpledge="number" name="clickandpledge_FirstName_PO" id="clickandpledge_FirstName_PO" class="required NameOnCard"  placeholder="First Name"/>
                              <input type="text" size="20" data-clickandpledge="number" name="clickandpledge_LastName_PO" id="clickandpledge_LastName_PO" class="required NameOnCard"  placeholder="Last Name"/> </label> </div> ';
             $html .= '<div style="display:'.$cdivdisplay.'" id="cnp_CreditCard_div">';
                         $html .= $clickandpledgename_CreditCard;
                          $html .= '<div class="form-row">
                            <label>
                              <span>'.__("Name On Card&nbsp;<font color='red'>*</font>", "wpjobboard").'</span>
                              <input type="text" size="20" data-clickandpledge="number" name="clickandpledge_nameOnCard" id="clickandpledge_nameOnCard" class="required NameOnCard"  placeholder="Name On Card"/></label> </div><div class="form-row">  <label>
                              <span>'.__("Card Number&nbsp;<font color='red'>*</font>", "wpjobboard").'</span>
                              <input type="text" size="20" data-clickandpledge="number" name="clickandpledge_cardNumber" id="clickandpledge_cardNumber" class="required creditcard" placeholder="Card Number"/></label> </div>  <div class="form-row"><label>
                              <span>'.__("CVV&nbsp;<font color='red'>*</font>", "wpjobboard").'</span>            
                              <input type="text" size="4" data-clickandpledge="cvc" maxlength="4" name="clickandpledge_cvc" id="clickandpledge_cvc" class="required Cvv2" placeholder="CVV"/>
 </label>  </div><div class="form-row">
                            <label><span>'.__("Expiration (MM/YYYY)&nbsp;<font color='red'>*</font>", "wpjobboard").'</span></label>
                            <select name="clickandpledge_cardExpMonth" id="clickandpledge_cardExpMonth" class="required">'.$this->getMonths().'</select> <span> / </span>
                            <select name="clickandpledge_cardExpYear" id="clickandpledge_cardExpYear" class="required" data-clickandpledge="exp-year">'.$this->getYears().'</select> </div>';
                        $html .= $recurringhtml;
                        $html .= '</div>'; //CreditCard Div End
```

some other payment types will come here

```
     $listing_id = '';
                if(isset($_POST['listing']) && $_POST['listing'] != '')
                $listing_id = $_POST['listing'];
                elseif(isset($_POST['listing_type']) && $_POST['listing_type'] != '')
                $listing_id = $_POST['listing_type'];
$varArray = array('clickandpledge_AccountID'=>$merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_'.$selectedCurrency.'_AccountID'],
                 'clickandpledge_AccountGuid'=>$merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_'.$selectedCurrency.'_AccountGuid'],'clickandpledge_OrderMode' => $merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_'.$selectedCurrency.'_OrderMode'],
                                    'clickandpledge_Amount' => $this->_data->payment_sum+$this->_data->payment_discount, 'clickandpledge_Discount' => $this->_data->payment_discount, 'clickandpledge_OrganizationInformation' => htmlspecialchars($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_OrganizationInformation']),'clickandpledge_TermsCondition' => htmlspecialchars($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_TermsCondition']),
                                    'clickandpledge_email_customer' => (is_array($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_emailcustomer']) && count($merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_emailcustomer']) > 0) ? $merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_emailcustomer'][0] : '',
                                    'clickandpledge_maxrecurrings_Subscription' => $merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_maxrecurrings_Subscription'],
                                    'clickandpledge_maxrecurrings_Installment' => $merchant['wpjobboard_clickandpledge_maxrecurrings_Installment'],
                                    'clickandpledge_listing_id' => $listing_id,
                                    'clickandpledge_coupon_code' => (isset($_POST['coupon'])) ? $_POST['coupon'] : '',
                                );
                                foreach($varArray as $k=>$v)
                                {
                                    $html.= '<input type="hidden" name="'.$k.'" id="'.$k.'" value="'.$v.'" />';
                                }
                              $html .= '<button type="submit">'.__("Submit Payment", "wpjobboard").'</button></div></form>';} else {
                if(count($availableCurrencies) > 0) {
                $html = 'Selected currency <b>'.$selectedCurrency.'</b> not supported by Click & Pledge. We are supporting <b>'.implode(',', $availableCurrencies).'</b> only. Please contact administrator.';} else {
                $html = 'Selected currency <b>'.$selectedCurrency.'</b> not supported by Click & Pledge. Please contact administrator.';
                }}return $html;        }
                         public function getMonths() {
                            $str = ''; for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                                if(date('m') == sprintf('%02d', $i)) {
                                $str .= '<option value="'.sprintf('%02d', $i).'" selected>'.sprintf('%02d', $i).' ('.strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2000)).')</option>';
                                } else {
                                $str .= '<option value="'.sprintf('%02d', $i).'">'.sprintf('%02d', $i).' ('.strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2000)).')</option>';
       }       }return $str; } public function getYears() {       $str = '';
                             for ($i = date('Y'); $i < date('Y') + 11; $i++) {
                                $str .= '<option value="'.strftime('%Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $i)).'">'.strftime('%Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $i)).'</option>';             
                            }
                            return $str; }
                         public function number_format($number, $decimals = 2,$decsep = '', $ths_sep = '') {
                $parts = explode('.', $number);
                if(count($parts) > 1) {
                return $parts[0].'.'.substr($parts[1],0,$decimals);
                } else {return $number;}} }
```

Comment: Didn't read if all your code but : add_fillter('wpjb_payments_list', 'wpjb_payment_vlickandpledge'); must be add_fillter('wpjb_payments_list', 'wpjb_payment_vlickandpledge',10, 2); as the function has 2 parameters.

Comment: I have form assigning to $html and in the first code , the default job plugin and payment systems in that list i have added my payment using filter, now my form is need to display under payment gateway list ,

Comment: Please [edit] you question, cut the code down to the absolute minimum, and bring it into a readable form (hint: indentation matters).